# Unable to push locally to a device (using balena) although I am able to ping the device explicitly

Tags: iot

I get an error when I am trying to push locally to a device. Although, I am able to ping it.

I am working on windows10 and running the cmd as an admin.

The below code has all the three commands I have used.
1.) “balena scan” discovers the available local device.
2.) “balena push” does not work.
3.) but ping works successfully.

```
D:\repository\FastBin\fast-bin-controller-dev>balena scan
Reporting scan results
-
  host:          56b2f81.local
  address:       172.30.112.88
  dockerInfo:
    Containers:        1
    ContainersRunning: 1
    ContainersPaused:  0
    ContainersStopped: 0
    Images:            2
    Driver:            aufs
    SystemTime:        2019-06-12T06:28:30.26445254Z
    KernelVersion:     4.9.34+
    OperatingSystem:   Resin OS 2.12.7+rev2
    Architecture:      armv7l
  dockerVersion:
    Version:    17.06.0-dev
    ApiVersion: 1.31

D:\repository\FastBin\fast-bin-controller-dev>ping 172.30.112.88

Pinging 172.30.112.88 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.30.112.88: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 172.30.112.88: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 172.30.112.88: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 172.30.112.88: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 172.30.112.88:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 1ms

D:\repository\FastBin\fast-bin-controller-dev>balena push 172.30.112.88
Could not communicate with local mode device at address 172.30.112.88

Additional information may be available by setting a DEBUG=1 environment
variable: "set DEBUG=1" on a Windows command prompt, or "export DEBUG=1"
on Linux or macOS.

If you need help, don't hesitate in contacting our support forums at
https://forums.balena.io

For bug reports or feature requests, have a look at the GitHub issues or
create a new one at: https://github.com/balena-io/balena-cli/issues/
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the version of the OS should be greater than or equal to 2.29 and mine was 2.12. After the upgrade, I was able to connect locally.

Thanks

Comment: one more thing that only development version of OS lets you connect locally , not production version.